# What is the best approach for confirming html form fields?

Tags: javascript, validation

A lot of times you get a form where you need to enter an email address (or other form field) twice in order to confirm that you typed it correctly the first time. Some forms disable the copy and paste action (via javascript) in the browser to force the user to type the email address again.

Personally I find this highly annoying. What are your thoughts? Are there other options?

Comment: Please change to a community wiki as this is an "opinion" question and not a technical question per se.

Comment: Your title doesn't really match your question. Your question is specific to email address confirmation but your title refers to all html form fields. What are you really asking?

Comment: the title refers to form fields, of which, emails can be one case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to check the email address you could implement a confirm email address function, which sends an email to the provided email address. The email could contain a link which allows the user to confirm his/her email address.

For obscured fields like password fields, it is always best to implement a double entry input field in case the user made a typo.

Comment: I could think of a few situations where the email address you're entereing is not your own.

Comment: Ok, so then you cannot validate your form submission (because that's where the email has been sent for) and it will be discarded.

Comment: And add a checkbox for revealing the password.

Comment: CAPTCHAs, double passwords and emails are always bad design. Developers should find real solutions to problems, not make users do twice as much job.

Comment: Whe is it "best to implement a double entry input field in case the user made a typo". Do you implement this for every field?

Comment: No, only for the password field, because it displays ***** instead of the characters...

Answer (score 0):

I find it highly annoying as well since, in many cases, the initial entry was done from an autofill that I know is correct.

Please note that this should be a community wiki!

Comment: No reason at all… one can opt-out of community wiki for his own answers anyway.

Comment: The very definition of "Community Wiki" questions is that they are ones wherein the community wrangles with subjective questions.  There is no "right" answer here - it is purely a matter of opinion.  Indeed, I made my answer a community wiki so that I wouldn't gain points from it.

Comment: And GS - you are incorrect to say that one can opt-out of community wiki for an answer (that you can get points somehow for answering a community wiki question).  You *can* opt IN to a community wiki - as I did - so that you *don't* get points but you cannot opt out.

Comment: I’ve always wondered how that “community wiki” wording would help anyone understand its meaning :-

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the site, if its something like a commerce site, I'd support disabling the copy and paste because if the address is typed in wrong it can cause pains for both the site and the customer. It's easier for everyone to just inconvenience the customer for 2 seconds during the process instead of having to deal with it later.

Answer (score 0):

I personally disagree with disabling the copy and paste thing. If the user enters the wrong email twice and identically (worst case scenario) it's his fault really.

Comment: Yes, but saying to the customer "well, it's your fault we sent out your private information to someone you don't know" won't make them feel any better.

Comment: @Beska:  That's why you first confirm that the address they entered works and is theirs.

Comment: @Eddie: that doesn't work if the email address they enter is on behalf of someone else

Comment: So have the user enter the same email three times. We could also throw in a JS popup after he tries to submit the form saying 'are you that's your email?' We could also make the password fields plain-text so he can be sure it's the right one, and have another popup for that. Overkill I say! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should just believe the user. If he mistypes the address, live with it.

First of all, if you confirm registration by sending an email, on the “Now wait for an email and click a confirmation link there” screen you can still show the address to which an email was sent. It can be followed by a link “Oops, mistypes my email address” letting you to correct yourself.

Second, if you use email for notifications, user will not get them, and, curious, he will go to his/her profile settings to check the notification parameters. You just have to make sure that “E-mail” input is next to “Get notifications” checkbox.